# How do i perform unsigned right shift( >>> in java) in VB.net (microsoft visual studio 2005)

Tags: vb.net, bit-shift

greeting, i'm newbie on VB.net
maybe this is silly question, but it make me stuck on my task
How do i perform unsigned right shift( >>> in java) in VB.net (microsoft visual studio 2005)

thank you for helping me :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an unsigned variable with the >> operator. If the variable you're shifting is unsigned, then the >> operator will propagate zeroes instead of the sign bit.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dezyht83%28v=vs.80%29.aspx